# Understanding abstract algebra proof of Fermat's Little Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

The following proof of Fermat's Little Theorem is taken verbatim from Fraleigh's A First Course in Abstract Algebra:

> **For any field, the nonzero elements form a group under the field multiplication.** In particular, for $\mathbb Z_p$, the elements $$1,2,3,\ldots,p-1$$ form a group of order $p-1$ under multiplication modulo $p$. Since the order of any element in a group divides the order of the group, we see that for $b\neq0$ and $b\in\mathbb Z_p$, we have $b^{p-1}=1$ in $\mathbb Z_p$. Using the fact that $\mathbb Z_p$ is isomorphic to the ring of cosets of the form $a+p\mathbb Z$, we see at once that for any $a\in\mathbb Z$ not in the coset $0+p\mathbb Z$, we must have $$a^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod{p}.$$

I have no problem following the proof, except for one thing. The whole proof makes no mention at all about how $p$ must be a prime. Hence it seems like this proof demonstrates Fermat's Little Theorem for all numbers $p$, not just primes, which is absurd! Where precisely does this proof break down when $p$ is not prime? What am I missing? (Sorry if this question is too trivial, but I couldn't find an explanation elsewhere.)

Comment: Hint: "For any *field* ...."

Comment: @BillDubuque Ah, but $\mathbb Z_n$ is a field if and only if every element is a unit, so every element is coprime to $n$, which is true exactly when $n$ is a prime, so that resolves the issue! Is that right?

Answer (score 2):

Due to the hint from [Bill Dubuque](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/242/bill-dubuque) and [Doug M](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/317162/doug-m), I think I have resolved my own problem. The bolded claim in the proof which is integral to the rest of the proof is only applicable when $\mathbb Z_p$ is indeed a field, which requires that every element in it has a multiplicative inverse, so each of them is coprime with the order of $\mathbb Z_{p}$. In order to have every $1,2,3,\ldots,p-1$ be coprime with $p$ we need $p$ to be prime.

Comment: Lagrange's Theorem on Finite Groups: If $G$ is  a finite group with $|G|=n$ (that is, if $G$ has $n$ members) and if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $|H|$ is a divisor of $|G|$.  Corollary: $\forall x\in G\,(x^{|G|}=1_G)$, where $1_G$ is the identity of $G$.... ( For $x\in G$ consider the subgroup $H_x=\{x^n:n\in \Bbb Z\})$..... Lagrange came long after Fermat................+1 to you

Answer (score 0):

the order of the multiplicative group $\bmod p$ is $\varphi(p)$ in general, it's just that if $p$ is prime we have $\varphi(p)=p-1$.

So in fact this is a proof of [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem).

Comment: But we don't know that the elements in $\mathbb Z_p$ coprime with $p$ form a multiplicative group! Yes, this is true, but it comes quite a bit later in my book in the section discussing Euler's Theorem. So for now I only have the bolded statement to use to prove FLittleT. Could you help pinpoint where in the given proof does it actually use the primality of $p$?

Comment: if $p$ is not prime then the nonzero elements dont form a group. This is easy to see because any non trivial divisor of $p$ has no inverse.